# Get running Activity of another Application in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an input method, and from the input method I would like to get the running activity of a package. I grab the package id from EditorInfo when the IME is loaded. Is there a way to get the id of the running activity from that package?

So if I have package id: com.guy.application
I get: com.guy.application.ActivityName

I then want to send an intent to this specific activity name.

How would I do this?

Comment: What makes you think that the activity in question will be set up to respond when you "send an intent"?

Comment: Nothing, Im just hoping. I am trying to send an image intent to the open conversation in whatever messaging application the user is using.

Comment: You need to use `Intent`s. You do not need the "id of a running activity". You share data via `Intent`s.

Comment: but I would like it to automatically select the open conversation